# How to dynamically call videos from a folder to play all the videos on loop in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a folder with 5 videos. I want to write a program in HTML/AngularJS to dynamically call the videos from the folder without having to mention the videos in a list.

```html
<video id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
   <source class="active" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" 
    type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

```js
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
   // get the active source and the next video source.
   // I set it so if there's no next, it loops to the first one
   var activesource = document.querySelector("#myvideo source.active");
   var nextsource = document.querySelector("#myvideo source.active + 
   source") || document.querySelector("#myvideo source:first-child");

   // deactivate current source, and activate next one
   activesource.className = "";
   nextsource.className = "active";

   // update the video source and play
   myvid.src = nextsource.src;
   myvid.play();
});
```

This code works if I explicitly mention the videos in the list in the program itself. But I don't want to do that.

Any way around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add more details about the context and requirements

Comment: Just edited it. I hope this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel, you want to achieve this by following way:

```js
const videoSrcList = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4",
  ...
];
var nextIndex = 1;
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
   var activesource = myvid.querySelector("source");
   activesource.src = videoSrcList[nextIndex];
   myvid.play();
});
```

```html
<video id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
   <source class="active" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" 
    type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: With a few edits, I was able to make this work. Thanks!